# How to get full screen when running Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox-guest-additions

I know this is a fairly commonly asked question, but I've followed the other solutions and none of them seem to solve my problem.
I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine on Virtualbox. I've set up the virtual machine all fine, but would like to view it in full screen mode, but I can't do this. When I go to full screen mode, the "Ubuntu screen" is still windowed and very small.

I know that this way this should work is by installing guest additions, and I've done this. I think it was successful, since when I run `lsmod | grep vboxguest`, I get the output: `vboxguest        45056   0`, which I gather means that the Virtualbox kernel module is installed and that the guest additions have been installed correctly.

However, when I try to go to full screen mode, it is still windowed and not full screen

What am I missing here? How can I get full screen?

EDIT: I've looked at: https://superuser.com/questions/408101/virtual-box-not-filling-entire-screen and
https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/
to try to get help

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/408101/virtual-box-not-filling-entire-screen

Comment: @wxz I've followed the advice there,  none of it actually solved my problem

Comment: Could you include all the sources of stuff you've tried? Otherwise we're all going to suggest sites you've seen.

Answer (score 19):

Right click on desktop and go to "**display settings**". There set **Resolution** to **1920:1200 (16:10)** or whichever is right for you. Click on **Apply**. Then a popup will appear, click **keep configurations**.
[image]

Comment: In my case it was 1920 x 1080 ( 16:9 )

Answer (score -1):

In virtualbox [Host Key] + F works for fullscreening.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4RCz.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).